# Simple or Complex? Issues with XML via PHP

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I am trying to display details as an echo via an XML file. It displays some of the details but not all of them.

I have tried several ways to do this any help would be great!

**Here's a snip of the XML Code.**

```
    <result>
    <rowset name="TestGroups" key="groupID" columns="groupName,groupID">
    <row groupName="Group 1" groupID="123">
      <rowset name="subGroup" key="typeID" columns="subgrName,groupID">
         <row subgrName="Sub Group A" groupID="123">...</row>
         <row subgrName="Sub Group b" groupID="123">...</row>
      </rowset>
    </row>

    <rowset name="TestGroups" key="groupID" columns="groupName,groupID">
    <row groupName="Group 2" groupID="456">
      <rowset name="subGroup" key="typeID" columns="subgrName,groupID">
         <row subgrName="Sub Group C" groupID="456">...</row>
         <row subgrName="Sub Group D" groupID="456">...</row>
      </rowset>
    </row>
    <result>
```

The Goal is to Output the information with an echo. Listing the Group followed by each SubGroup.

**The following is a snip of current php code :**

```
    $string = file_get_contents("Calls the XML FILE");

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
    $xml_short = $xml->result->rowset->row ;  
    $xml_short2 = $xml->result->rowset->row->rowset->row ;  



    foreach ($xml_short as $row ) {

    echo $row{'groupName'};

         foreach ($xml_short2 as $row2 ) {


           echo $row{'subgrName'};

         }

    }
```

**The current output :**

```
    Group 1
    Group 2
```

**The output that i need is :**

```
    Group 1
       Sub Group A
       Sub Group B

    Group 2
       Sub Group C
       Sub Group D
```

I think that I am on the right track. The idea was to return each group. loop to get the Sub Groups then move on to the next group and repeat until all are done.

I have tried several different ways and all seem to fail or not work properly. So any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many `row` as array and you should set `$xml_short2` inside `foreach` like following

```
foreach ($xml_short as $row) {

    echo $row{'groupName'};

    $xml_short2 = $row->rowset->row;

    foreach ($xml_short2 as $row2) {
       echo $row2{'subgrName'};
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, That gives the same output that I have. It still does not show (echo) the subgrName's.

Comment: Regarding my prior post, I forgot to modify the snip I made for the post. I am very very thankful!!!! I tried for ever to figure it out. Thanks again